# Chrome Extension: Execute extension when page is loaded

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

i am working on a extension that is running correctly at the moment BUT only when i click on the extension-icon.

What i want is, that the extension gets executed automatically when the webpage is loaded.
What needs to be executed is my .js-file.

How can i handle this problem/feature?

Comment: Use [Content scripts](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/content_scripts.html).

Comment: hmm, i tried a few things now but its still not working

Comment: Can you show your code, and define "not working"?

Comment: i edited the manifest only. here is the code: http://pastie.org/4383519

Comment: and this is the code of the popup.js: http://pastie.org/4383528

Comment: Do you *really* want to open a popup whenever you navigate to a page on YouTube...? If yes, remove line 1 and 11 of `popup.js`, because content scripts are executed in a context which approximates the specific page.

Comment: i removed line 1 and 11 but its still not working.

i cant see any errors or something else. the page is loading and nothing happens.

Comment: Replace `tab.url` with `location.href`. You *should have* received an error message. Open the console at YouTube, and you should see `ReferenceError: tab is not defined`.

Comment: oh wow, i dont know where my mistake was. but now it showed the "tab not defined"-error. i fixed it and now its working! :)

Answer (score 0):

Method `chrome.tabs.getSelected` is deprecated in manifest version 2. You should use [`chrome.tabs.query({active : true, currentWindow : true}, callback)`](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/tabs.html#method-query) instead, if you want to get the currently active tab, or [`chrome.tabs.query({url : '...'}, callback)`](https://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/tabs.html#method-query) if you want to get tabs by matching the URL pattern.

Comment: Same as the other answer (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11801845/get-tab-url-from-chrome-extension-in-javascript)....  getCurrent does not return the currently active tab, it returns the tab that the script is run in.