# Get tab url from Chrome Extension in Javascript

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, popup

I tried looking around Stackoverflow but couldn't find anything specifically for this.

So basically, I have a share page for my website that goes like this:

```
http://domain.com/share.php?link=http://sharing.url
```

My extension goes like this:

```
{
 ...
  "browser_action": {
   "default_icon": "icon.ico",
   "default_popup": "schare.html"
 }
...
}
```

schare.html:

```
<style>
body, html{
margin:0;
padding:0;
}
iframe{
    width:520px;
    height:200px;
    margin:0;
}
</style>
<iframe id="iframes" frameborder="0"></iframe>
<script type="text/javascript" src="popup.js"></script>
```

and popup.js:

```
document.getElementById("iframes").setAttribute("src", "http://domain.com/share.php?link="+location.href+"");
```

But that's the wrong URL. How can I get the tab url in there without doing anything too fancy?

Comment: Do you want to share a `chrome-extension:`-URL...?

Answer (score 1):

The code below may not work if you have an array of tabs in the current window and not just one. Here's a modified version

`chrome.tabs.query({active : true, currentWindow: true}, function (tabs) {
    var tab = (tabs.length === 0 ? tabs : tabs[0]);

    var activeTabUrl = tab.url;
});`

Answer (score 0):

You can get the currently active tab by calling [`chrome.tabs.query`](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/tabs.html#method-query). The callback function will receive the [reference to the tab](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/tabs.html#type-Tab) as an argument.

So to get the URL of active tab, you can use this:

```
chrome.tabs.query({active : true, currentWindow: true}, function (tab) {
    var activeTabUrl = tab.url;
});
```

Note, that the `getCurrent()` method uses a callback, so don't try to use in a linear code.

Comment: Wait... So like this?
`code
    chrome.tabs.getCurrent(function (tab) {
        var activeTabUrl = tab.url;
    });
    document.getElementById("iframes").setAttribute("src", "http://domain.com/share.php?link="+activeTabUrl+"");`

Comment: getCurrent does not return the currently active tab, it returns the tab that the script is run in (which considering his script is run in the popup will be undefined).  What you want is to query for the active tab in the current window, like so... `chrome.tabs.query({active:true,currentWindow:true},function(tab){document.getElementById("iframes").setAttribute("src", "http://domain.com/share.php?link="+tab.url+"");});` Please update your answer with the correct information and thanks for trying ;)

Comment: Ahh, my bad. Sorry for the mistake. Thanks, PAEz.

Comment: i tries this code (copy-paste) and still get undefined when script runs from popup :(

Comment: don't forget to add
`"permissions": [
        "tabs",
        "http://*/*"
    ]`
in your manifest, otherwise the url field will be undefined